# Why can't I install AppKit from mac terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, appkit

Tried to install AppKit through terminal it through terminal, want to work with speech recognition, this error shows up, how do I fix it, do I need to install pyobjc?

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python /Users/saqlainsajid/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/cj/3q_3db6537gfp2g6fkntpy0h0000gp/T/pip-build-env-Lim5sb/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel pycairo
       cwd: None
  Complete output (31 lines):
  DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-44.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (583 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
  Collecting pycairo
    Downloading pycairo-1.18.2.tar.gz (200 kB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: pycairo
    WARNING: Building wheel for pycairo failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/saqlainsajid/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/8a'
  Failed to build pycairo
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, pycairo
      Running setup.py install for pycairo: started
      Running setup.py install for pycairo: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/cj/3q_3db6537gfp2g6fkntpy0h0000gp/T/pip-install-JoFyAI/pycairo/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/cj/3q_3db6537gfp2g6fkntpy0h0000gp/T/pip-install-JoFyAI/pycairo/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/cj/3q_3db6537gfp2g6fkntpy0h0000gp/T/pip-record-GrpDGI/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/cj/3q_3db6537gfp2g6fkntpy0h0000gp/T/pip-build-env-Lim5sb/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/cj/3q_3db6537gfp2g6fkntpy0h0000gp/T/pip-build-env-Lim5sb/overlay/include/python2.7/pycairo
           cwd: /private/var/folders/cj/3q_3db6537gfp2g6fkntpy0h0000gp/T/pip-install-JoFyAI/pycairo/
      Complete output (12 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/cairo
      copying cairo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/cairo
      copying cairo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/cairo
      copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/cairo
      running build_ext
      'pkg-config' not found.
      Command ['pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo >= 1.13.1']
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/cj/3q_3db6537gfp2g6fkntpy0h0000gp/T/pip-install-JoFyAI/pycairo/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/cj/3q_3db6537gfp2g6fkntpy0h0000gp/T/pip-install-JoFyAI/pycairo/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/cj/3q_3db6537gfp2g6fkntpy0h0000gp/T/pip-record-GrpDGI/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/cj/3q_3db6537gfp2g6fkntpy0h0000gp/T/pip-build-env-Lim5sb/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/cj/3q_3db6537gfp2g6fkntpy0h0000gp/T/pip-build-env-Lim5sb/overlay/include/python2.7/pycairo Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python /Users/saqlainsajid/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/cj/3q_3db6537gfp2g6fkntpy0h0000gp/T/pip-build-env-Lim5sb/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel pycairo Check the logs for full command output.
```